# Graphing in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I have these values

Temperature 
4
25
37
55
80

and

Rate
.1235
.092
.0864
.057
.0044

I wish to create a bar graph with Rate on the X-axis and Temp on the Y-axis.

I create a spreadsheet with the values and highlight the data.

Then I click on insert clustered column graph.

However, it gives me temp on the y axis and the numbers 1 through 5 on the x axis.

How can I make it so Rate is on the X-axis and Temp is on the Y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Isn't rate going to be dependent on temperature? If so, temperature should be the independent variable (X) and rate the dependent variable (Y).
2. Aren't these continuous measurable quantities? If so, rather than a bar chart, you should probably make an XY Scatter chart. (As Pnuts hinted at.)

Put your X values into a column, and your Y values into the next column, as shown below, then insert an XY Scatter chart. I used the style with markers and straight lines.

[image]